# What is Dijkstra's algorithm supposed to return?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm a front-end Javascript developer but wanted to learn some graph theory to prepare for a Google interview, I looked up some implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm.

The example listed here 
https://github.com/mburst/dijkstras-algorithm/blob/master/dijkstras.js
seems to be suited for finding the shortest path between two nodes and returns the shortest node path between them, but the pseudocode version on wikipedia seems to return both "prev, and dist"--- what are they supposed to be?

I tried modifying the github example to match the wikipedia pseudocode and returning distances does seem to give the shortest numerical distances to each one from the startVertex... but prev is not returning the shortest paths

```
var INFINITY = 1/0;

function PriorityQueue () {
  this._nodes = [];

  this.enqueue = function (priority, key) {
    this._nodes.push({key: key, priority: priority });
    this.sort();
  }
  this.dequeue = function () {
    return this._nodes.shift().key;
  }
  this.sort = function () {
    this._nodes.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.priority - b.priority;
    });
  }
  this.isEmpty = function () {
    return !this._nodes.length;
  }
}


function Graph(){
  this.vertices = {};

  this.addVertex = function(name, edges){
    edges = edges || null;
    this.vertices[name] = edges;
  }
}


function djikstra(graph, startVertex) {
  var nodes = new PriorityQueue();

  var distances = {};
  var previous = {};

  for(vertex in graph.vertices) {
    if (vertex === startVertex) {
      distances[vertex] = 0;
      nodes.enqueue(0, vertex);
    } else {
      distances[vertex] = INFINITY;
      nodes.enqueue(INFINITY, vertex);
    }

    previous[vertex] = null;
  }


  while(!nodes.isEmpty()) {
    var smallest = nodes.dequeue();

    for(var neighbor in graph.vertices[smallest]) {
      var alt = distances[smallest] + graph.vertices[smallest][neighbor];

      if(alt < distances[neighbor]) {
        distances[neighbor] = alt;
        previous[neighbor] = smallest;
      }
    }
  }

  return distances;
}

var graph = new Graph();

graph.addVertex('S', {V: 1, W: 4});
graph.addVertex('V', {W: 2, T: 6});
graph.addVertex('W', {T: 3});
graph.addVertex('T');


console.log(djikstra(graph, 'S'));
//
{ S: 0, V: 1, W: 3, T: 6 }
```

Comment: This implementation appears to be returning the length of the shortest path to each node from the given node, in this case `S`.

Comment: depending on ur need, it can return the sum of all vertices in the path and/or the path.

Comment: what is prev supposed to be in the wikipedia pseudocode?

Comment: @WinchenzoMagnifico `prev` is a table that, for each vertex `v`, contains the node that precedes `v` on the discovered shortest path from `S` to `v`.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 4):

Dijkstra algorithm is an algorithm which gives you the shortest distance from some point to all other points for a non-negative graph.

There are many different modifications. You can return distance between two nodes, distances between a node and all other nodes, distance and a path, distance and a previous node (which is enough to construct a path).

So in the case of wikipedia article - it returns you distances to all vertices and what is the previous vertex in the path to get your path.

**P.S.** If you want to prepare for an interview, I suggest you to stop looking at random github repos (it may be really hard to understand the code of a particular person, which might be wrong/suboptimal), but instead open a book and try to understand the logic behind the algorithm. Especially if the algorithm can be written in < 50 lines.

Comment: I tried looking up the algorithm in CLRS but that was even harder to understand than looking at actual code-- the thing is one line of those 50 lines actually takes more than just one line to be implemented